# Is there a way to convert JOptionPane from Swing to JavaFX?

Tags: swing, javafx

I have been trying to convert the following Swing code to JavaFX.

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,"X","Y", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);`

This code is ultimately returned as a string by a method call. But I do not know how to rewrite it in JavaFX.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `TextInputDialog`:

```
TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
dialog.setHeaderText("X");
dialog.setTitle("Y");
Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Since my method has to return a String, I do not understand how I could do that? Is there any way that Optional<String> can be used as a String?

Comment: @B.Dave: It's mentioned in the javadocs ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html ) You could use `isPresent`, `get` and/or `orElse`